# Firefox to auto fill password ONLY by using keyboard shortcut

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, password-management

I've tried LastPass and RoboForm. They both fill the id/pwd form upon load the page. While I wish the auto form fill only happens when use keyboard shortcut (like press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>). Is there any way to configure this? Or any other password management add-on can do this? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting configuration setting [`signon.autofillForms`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Signon.autofillForms) to `false`.

Comment: I guess you meant to write `false`

Comment: @unor: oops, the correct value is indeed `false`. It's `true` by default already. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:
Tools --> Options --> Security ---> Use a master password

after you set a master password you have to type master password and then your User/pass will appear.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However, this is still not what I am looking for though.

Comment: @Stan: I know you need to use keyboard. but I thought there is no way for this, but master password is.

Comment: It's a nice solution. However, I often need to type login info in front others. That's why I want to avoid typing any kind of password. However, I don't want the id/pwd auto-fill directly. That's why I am asking a keyboard shortcut way to do this.

Comment: So, if I find using keyboard shortcut I will tell you! ;)